# SWIFT: Any Way To Create Nested Enums with Relationships?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, nested

I would like to know if its possible to create nested Enums with defined relationships in Swift.

Example:

```
Cities.Boston.Streets.<streets in Boston>
Cities.Boston.Avenues.<avenues in Boston>
Cities.Chicago.Streets.<streets in Chicago>
Cities.Chicago.Avenues.<avenues in Chicago>
```

Comment: You can nest multiple ENUMs. But you will end up with a lot of code if you are looking for all cities. `enum Cities {}` `extension Cities {enum Boston{} enum Chicago{}}` `extension Boston {enum Streets {}}`

Comment: I'm just using Cities and streets as an example, my real world scenario will have much less combinations. Could you post an example of the solution you proposed, using extensions sounds interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
enum Cities {}

extension Cities {
    enum Boston{}
    enum Chicago{}
}

extension Cities.Boston {
    enum Streets {
        case Ave
        case AveN
    }
}
```

Likewise you can extend for `Cities.Chicago` then you can access it like `Cities.Boston.Streets.Ave`

Only reason extensions are added is to have it in a structured way. Its all the same if you define in the main `Cities` enum as well.

Not sure what you mean when you say you are looking for enums with relationships.

Comment: it is possible `protocol LocationProtocol{}` to have it some construct like this: `var location:LocationProtocol?` where i can do `enum Streets: String, LocationProtocol` and later assign `location = Cities.Boston.Streets.secondStreet` and also `location = Cities.Chicago.Avenues.firstAvenue`. but how i can print the whole name if i add `func address() -> String` to the `LocationProtocol`

Comment: i would like to see `print(Cities.Boston.Avenues.firstAvenue.address)` -> `Bosten City\nFirst Avenue`